# How to have Angular uses HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Tags: angular

I use the standard Angular http module to sent post requests to an on-prem virtual machine. It doesn't work because Angular keeps sending HTTPS requests instead of HTTP requests.

Sample of the code I use for a POST:

```
myFunction(request: MyType): any {
   const uri = "http://myVirtualMachine/myApi/myService";
   const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'};
   return this.http.post<any>(uri, request, {headers});
}
```

This works if I the POST is sent to localhost. For any other URI, HTTP is always replaced with HTTPS.

**Any clue why and how to fix this?**

Some notes:

- Angular 12.
- No interceptor, but if I add an interceptor, the request received by it contains HTTP, not HTTPS.
- Same issue in Edge and Chrome, in private mode or not, and even after having cleared all the caches I can think of.
- Domain security policy doesn't seems to be the issue here (chrome://net-internals/#hsts).

Comment: I can’t imagine this has anything to do with Angular..?

Comment: @MikeOne I can be wrong. But I did many tests, asked colleagues, and so far, everything point toward the Angular Http module. If you have any suggestion, do not hesitate, I will take all! Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you simply open http://myVirtualMachine/myApi/myService" in your browser? Does it stay http?

Comment: If you open DevTools and look at the network request it will actually tell you which code was responsible for the call. Like a stacktrace. Should be easy to spot the offender using that and some breakpoints

Comment: I think it's because of http://myVirtualMachine/myApi/myService this url was redirecting from your server side in https://myVirtualMachine/myApi/myService. Can you please check your server configuration?

Comment: I have called http url in my browser it will automatically redirect me in https.

Comment: @MikeOne If I open the web API link in Chrome/Edge (Help Page), it works fine. No HTTPS.

Comment: it's a mystery ;-) - not sure what else to suggest. Did you try to break the link by appending a random character to the URL in your code? Just to make sure the request you're looking at is actually the request that is being sent?

Comment: ..other things to check - if the request happens (through your code) and you look at your network console, do you see any 301 or 302 redirects? Also - do you have any proxy configs in the root of project?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, I did change the URL to random chars, and even random ports, still getting HTTPS - unless it's localhost, any port - real mystery !!

Comment: @AmanGojariya Good advice! Sadly, when I place a breakpoint in the last entry of the stack trace, I still see HTTP, not HTTPS. Btw, the last entry is scheduleTask in zone.js. 
But thanks!

Comment: @AmanGojariya Regarding the server configuration: My Angular 12 app send HTTPS post requests even if I use a random, non-existing URL :(

Comment: @MikeOne I finally found what changed http into https - see below. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you found it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit was this line in index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

I'm not sure how it get there, maybe when I installed msal.js for a test.

Comment: I don't have this line in index.html. Still it is redirecting to https instead of http.